# Logical Tests in UPDATE...SET queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2022

I need to add some columns to a table whose values depend on existing columns. Using `UPDATE...SET` (I assumed). I can't get it to work. Simple reprex:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    cost decimal(10,2),
    ref int
);

INSERT INTO my_table(cost, ref)
VALUES      (0.00, 1),
            (0.50, 1),
            (-1.89, 1),
            (0.00, 2),
            (0.00, 2),
            (0.00, 2),
            (1.23, 3),
            (-9.47, 3),
            (111.23, 3),
            (12.00, 3);
    
-- want a field that denotes positive or negative cost values
    
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD         cost_sign bit;
    
UPDATE my_table
SET    cost_sign = (cost > 0);
```

This gives me an error: `Incorrect syntax near '>'`.

Can someone help me fix this please?

Comment: It's almost always a mistake to *store* that which can be *calculated*. All you do by introducing this redundant data is introduce the possibility for it to *be inconsistent* with the original data. Why did you *think* you needed to add this column?

Comment: Agree with above, even computed column is overkill, unless the formula is very complicated / long to type out, which sign definitely ain't

Comment: @siggemannen if you needed to implemented the `sign` (or whatever simple logic) in 20 different queries and then you needed to change the logic in any way at a later date, you'd be kicking yourself for not using a computed column.

Answer (score 2):

The boolean expression `cost > 0` is not behaving as expected.  Try using a `CASE` expression as the RHS of the assignment:

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET cost_sign = CASE WHEN cost > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

The comment by @Damien is valid and you may not even want to maintain this computed column as it is storing derived data.  Should the `cost` data change, you could be forced to run this update again.  Instead, look into using a generated column.

Comment: Thank you. That works. So do logical operators like =, <>, AND, NOT, etc. not work inside queries in the way I've tried to use them?

Comment: SQL Server does not support boolean expressions in this way.

Comment: `cost_sign` was already defined as a `BIT` column.  The bigger issue is making sure that the literals on the RHS of the assignment are valid for `BIT` (0 and 1 are fine).

Comment: thanks - yeah I deleted my comment because I remembered that I'd already defined `cost_sign` earlier

Answer (score 2):

What you need here is a computed column; you can use the [sign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD Cost_Sign as sign(cost);
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, but how does SQL know which data type to use for `cost_sign`?

Comment: @Alan In your case it should be `decimal` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#return-types

Comment: Yup as stated in the documentation the return type is dependent on the expression passed; you could of course cast it as required.